# Can someone please explain this notation of Lp space?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Can someone please explain what is the meaning of $(L^p(\Omega))^{N+1}$?

Comment: Where did you find this notation?

Comment: @DMcMor I found this in a paper on PDEs (kinetic theory)

Comment: There's an extra parenthesis there. I presume it's the $(N+1)$-fold cartesian product of the vector space $L^p(\Omega)$ with itself. I.e., if you write $V=L^p(\Omega)$, it's $V^{N+1}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you! I just made the correction and your explanation makes a lot of sense!

Comment: @DMcMor may I ask what paper in kinetic theory? I'm just curious no pressure to give me an answer.